# How to build LineageOS without certain default apps?

Tags: android, android-source, lineageos

I have a Pixel 7, codename Panther for which I want to build a custom LineageOS based ROM. I have pulled the source code, pulled in the proprietary blobs that are required and pulled in the device specific code. So the next steps is to run the actual build command.

Before doing that I wanted to build the ROM without some of the default apps that are included, what manifest file should I edit to have the ROM built without these apps: `Dailer, Music, MusicFX, PhoneCommon, Recorder, QuickAccessWallet, EmergencyInfo, Messaging`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to modify an existing LineageOS image and remove these apps from it? Or is your primary goal to learn building LineageOS?

Comment: @Robert I would like to ultimately learn how to build my own ROM and issue updates but this manifest file that designates which apps are built I cannot find nor can I find any documentation on.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file(s) are just meant for syncing the source code repositories from the respective git remotes. Removing the respective entries will just remove them from syncing to your build machine. This will cause a build error instead. So to actually remove the apps from building, you have to remove the apps from the list of `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` declared in the source.
For example, check .mk files here : https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/tree/lineage-21.0/config